# What does the '`' character do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was using Perl to read through each line of a file. I used a command line tool to call a service, and I noticed some interesting functionality that I can't figure out how to search for.  To the variable `$cmd` I assigned the command that invokes the service. If I refer to `$cmd` later in the code it prints out the command line argument, but if I refer to it as `` `$cmd` ``, however, it gives the output from running the service.

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works just like backquotes in the shell, which is why it is called that.  See *sh*(1) for details.  It captures the standard output alone, and nothing else. It sets the `$?` variable to the 16-bit wait status word.

This is all explained in the [*perlop*(1) manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60):

> **`qx/STRING/`**
>   **`` `STRING` ``**
>            A string which is (possibly) interpolated and then
>              executed as a system command with `/bin/sh` or its
>              equivalent.  Shell wildcards, pipes, and redirections
>              will be honored.  The collected standard output of the
>              command is returned; standard error is unaffected.  In
>              scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially
>              multi-line) string, or undef if the command failed.
>              In list context, returns a list of lines (however
>              you’ve defined lines with [`$/` or
>              `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)), or the empty list if the
>              command failed.
>
> Because backticks do not affect standard error: use
>              shell file descriptor syntax (assuming the shell
>              supports this) if you care to address this.  To
>              capture a command’s `STDERR` and `STDOUT` merged together:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1`;
> ```
>
> To capture a command’s `STDOUT` but discard its `STDERR`:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>/dev/null`;
> ```
>
> To capture a command’s `STDERR` but discard its `STDOUT`
>              (ordering is important here):
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
> ```
>
> To exchange a command’s `STDOUT` and `STDERR` in order to
>              capture the `STDERR` but leave its `STDOUT` to come out
>              the old `STDERR`:
>
> ```
> $output = `cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-`;
> ```
>
> To read both a command’s `STDOUT` and its `STDERR`
>              separately, it’s easiest to redirect them separately
>              to files, and then read from those files when the
>              program is done:
>
> ```
>  system("program args 1>program.stdout 2>program.stderr");
> ```
>
> The `STDIN` filehandle used by the command is inherited
>              from Perl’s `STDIN`.  For example:
>
> ```
> open(BLAM, "blam")     || die "$0: can't open blam: $!";
> open (STDIN, "<&BLAM") || die "$0: can't dup BLAM: $!";
> print `sort`;
> ```
>
> will print the sorted contents of the file `blam`.
>
> Using single-quote as the delimiter protects the command
>              from Perl’s double-quote interpolation, passing the contents on
>              to the shell instead:
>
> ```
> $perl_info  = qx(ps $$);    # that's Perl's $$
> $shell_info = qx'ps $$';    # that's the new shell's $$
> ```
>
> How that string gets evaluated is entirely subject to
>              the command interpreter on your system.  On most
>              platforms, you will have to protect shell
>              metacharacters if you want them treated literally.
>              This is in practice difficult to do, as it’s unclear
>               which characters need escaping, or how.  See [*perlsec*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) for a
>              clean and safe example of a manual [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) and [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)
>              to emulate backticks safely.
>              On some platforms (notably DOS-like ones), the shell
>              may not be capable of dealing with multiline commands,
>              so putting newlines in the string may not get you what
>              you want.  You may be able to evaluate multiple
>              commands in a single line by separating them with the
>              command separator character, if your shell supports
>              that (e.g. `;` on many Unix shells; `&` on the Windows
>              NT *CMD.COM* shell).
>
> Beginning with v5.6.0, Perl attempts to flush all
>              files opened for output before starting the child
>              process, but this may not be supported on some
>              platforms (see [*perlport*(1)](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport)).  To be safe, you may need to
>              set [`$|` (`$AUTOFLUSH` in English)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) or call the
>              `autoflush` method of [IO::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aHandle) on any open
>              handles.
>
> Beware that some command shells may place restrictions
>              on the length of the command line.  You must ensure
>              your strings don’t exceed this limit after any
>              necessary interpolations.  See [the platform-specific
>              release notes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport) for more details about your particular
>              environment.
>
> Using this operator can lead to programs that are
>              difficult to port, because the shell commands called
>              vary between systems, and may in fact not be present
>              at all.  As one example, the *type* command under the
>              POSIX shell is very different from the *type* command
>              under DOS.  That doesn't mean you should go out of
>              your way to avoid backticks when they’re the right way
>              to get something done.  Perl was made to be a glue
>              language, and one of the things it glues together is
>              commands.  Just understand what you’re getting
>              yourself into.
>
> See [I/O Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) for more discussion.

Here’s a simple example of using backticks to get the exit status of the first element in a pipeline:

```
$device = q(/dev/rmt8);
$dd_noise = q(^[0-9]+\+[0-9]+ records (in|out)$);
$status = `exec 3>&1; ((dd if=$device ibs=64k 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- 4>&-; echo $? >&4) |  egrep -v "$dd_noise" 1>&2 3>&- 4>&-) 4>&1`;
```

---

## EDIT

Well ok then, so maybe that wasn’t *that* simple an example. :)  But this one is.

I’d like to recommend the [*Capture::Tiny* CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) as a simpler way to manage the output from external commands that you would normally run using backquotes. It has advantages and disadvantages, but I feel that for many people, the advantages outweigh any arguable disadvantageL

- The **advantage** is that you get to do all this *without* requiring deep knowledge of arcane mysteries of file-descriptor redirection the way the previous example did.
- The **disadvantage** is it’s yet another non-core dependency — something else you have to install from CPAN.

That’s really not bad for what you get.

Here’s an example of how easy it is:

> **NAME**
>
> [*Capture::Tiny*](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) - Capture STDOUT and STDERR from Perl, [XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlwin32), or external programs
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>     use Capture::Tiny qw/capture tee capture_merged tee_merged/;
>
>      ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
>         # your code here
>       };
>
>      ($stdout, $stderr) = tee {
>         # your code here
>       };
>
>      $merged = capture_merged {
>         # your code here
>       };
>
>      $merged = tee_merged {
>         # your code here
>       };
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) provides a simple, portable way to capture anything sent to STDOUT or STDERR, regardless of whether it comes from Perl, from [XS code](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlxs)
>          or from an external program.  Optionally, output can be teed so that it is captured while being passed through to the original handles.  Yes, it
>          even works on [Windows](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlwin32).  Stop guessing which of a dozen capturing modules to use in any particular situation and just use this one.

There, isn’t that a whole lot easier?

Comment: I used to have problems with Capture::Tiny and binmodes (they kept switching to ISO Latin, AFAIK). I don't remember the details, just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 3):

The back-quote in Perl does much the same as the back-quote in shell - it runs a command and captures the standard output.

See also [qx//](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: Rather, it captures their stdout — whatever they emit on filed descriptor 1.  Stuff on other file descriptors is not captured.

Comment: @tchrist: yes, but then the shell only captures standard output, too.

Comment: Well, technically.  But you can always play with your file descriptors to arrange for the right part to be on 1.  It can be a regular 3-ring circus.  Or 4. :)

Comment: @tchrist: yes, and (unless you have a C Shell instead of real shell), you can do the same gyrations with file descriptors inside the command executed via back-quotes.

Comment: I know: do you not recognize the `2>&1 1>&3 3>&- 4>&-` reference? It’s from *Csh Programming Considered Harmful*, something like 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think the backtick lets you run commands and store their output in a variable:

```
$listing=`ls -1 /tmp/`;
```

Comment: What output?  You mean their `stdout`.  It doesn’t get their `stderr`, their `/dev/tty`, nor anything else but `stdout`.